# Training certification developer frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, certification

Is There someone who has passed or possesses examples of question for the certificate developer frontend or otherwise for a training.

Comment: @prince I have passed `magento certified developer` and `frontend certified Developer` Exams

Comment: Cool, could you tell me if you have some examples test

Comment: http://magento-quiz.magestore.com/